# What is wrong with my regex (simple)?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to make a regex that matches all occurrences of words that are at the start of a line and begin with #.

For example in:

```
#region #like
#hey
```

It would match #region and #hey.

This is what I have right now:

```
^#\w*
```

I apologize for posting this question. I'm sure it has a very simple answer, but I have been unable to find it. I admit that I am a regex noob.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your RegEx. Maybe you use it wrong? `Regex.Match("#region #like", @"^#\w*").Groups[0].Value`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've got should work, depending on what flags you pass for [RegexOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx). You need to make sure you pass `RegexOptions.Multiline`:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"^#\w*", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

See the documentation I linked to above:

> **Multiline** Multiline mode. Changes the meaning of ^ and $ so they match at the beginning and end, respectively, of any line, and not just the beginning and end of the entire string.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I knew I was doing something stupid. Will accept your answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

The regex looks fine, make sure you're using a *verbatim string literal* (@ prefix) to define your regex, i.e. `@"^#\w*"` otherwise the backslash will be treated as an escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex

```
^#.+?\b
```

`.+` will ensure at least one character after `#` and `\b` indicates word boundry. `?` adds non-greediness to the `+` operator so as to avoid matching whole string `#region #like`